# htaccess language redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, multilingual

I've been looking for the answers here but I can't get what I need.
I want to redirect pages looking to the 'l' language variable. The site is in spanish and english.

So I need a pattern like this:

```
mysite.com/page1/**?l=en**
mysite.com/page2/page2b**?l=en**
```

Redirect to:

```
mysite.com**/en/**page1
mysite.com**/en/**page2/page2b
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1? [L,R]
```

Or this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (GET|HEAD)\ /([^\?]+)\?l=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%3/$1? [L,R]
```

Will both make it so when someone types something like `http://domain.com/blah?l=foo` in the browser's URL address bar, the rule redirects *the browser* to `http://domain.com/foo/blah` and this URL will be what is shown in the address bar.